# linear algebra from beginner to intermediate level

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I was wondering if there is a way to learn linear algebra from beginner to advanced level by studying it myself. I want to collect a number of books, video lectures, tutorials and other resources to learn it. Stackoverflow has a [similar question on learning C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), so I thought this would be a good place to ask this question.

Two things:
1. Open video lectures, if any, will be really helpful.
2. As I am trying to self study, problem oriented books (possibly with hints and solutions) will be very helpful.

Comment: [MIT's OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) is very helpful for these sorts of things.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this. If someone can make this question as wiki, that would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm also really interested to hear if somebody has a coherent strategy. My own linear algebra experience was so fragmented, repeating the same material many (6) times at different depths, that I have a hard time imagining what a streamlined experience would look like.

Comment: @rivu: You might want to peruse these: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79674/rigorous-text-in-multivariable-calculus-and-linear-algebra?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192552/how-to-self-study-linear-algebra?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189317/a-first-course-in-linear-algebra-and-applications?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99994/first-course-in-linear-algebra-books-that-start-with-basic-algebra?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79674/rigorous-text-in-multivariable-calculus-and-linear-algebra?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You could try this link. It covers the basics and you could use it also for organizing your learning. I mean what to start with and what to learn next.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/